# PHP Convert multidimensional array key to be array multidimensional value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have problem formatting array to become [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) format, below array output from db:

```
array(44) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "35"
    ["title"]=>
    string(28) "ROOT1"
    ["path"]=>
    string(28) "ROOT1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "36"
    ["title"]=>
    string(27) "SUB_A"
    ["path"]=>
    string(56) "ROOT1>SUB_A"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "39"
    ["title"]=>
    string(12) "SUB_A_1"
    ["path"]=>
    string(69) "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "37"
    ["title"]=>
    string(28) "SUB_A_2"
    ["path"]=>
    string(85) "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "40"
    ["title"]=>
    string(30) "SUB_A_3"
    ["path"]=>
    string(87) "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_3"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "43"
    ["title"]=>
    string(19) "SUB_A_4"
    ["path"]=>
    string(76) "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_4"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "41"
    ["title"]=>
    string(12) "SUB_A_5"
    ["path"]=>
    string(69) "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_5"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(20) "ROOT2"
    ["path"]=>
    string(20) "ROOT2"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["title"]=>
    string(37) "ROOT3"
    ["path"]=>
    string(37) "ROOT3"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "34"
    ["title"]=>
    string(21) "SUB_B"
    ["path"]=>
    string(59) "ROOT3>SUB_B"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "31"
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "SUB_C"
    ["path"]=>
    string(53) "ROOT3>SUB_C"
  }
```

I want to format values of `path` become structured array, here is what I try:

```php
function format(array $data) : array
{
    $single = [];
    // format to single data
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $single[] = $value['path'];
    }

    $result = [];
    foreach ($single as $path) {
        $parts       = explode('>', $path);
        $section     = &$result;
        $sectionName = '';
        
        
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            
            $sectionName = $part;
            
            if (array_key_exists($sectionName, $section) === FALSE) {
                $section[$sectionName] = [];
            }
                $section = &$section[$sectionName];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

result:

```
array(3) {
  ["ROOT1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["SUB_A"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["SUB_A_1"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["SUB_A_2"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["SUB_A_3"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["SUB_A_4"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["SUB_A_5"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["ROOT2"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ROOT3"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["SUB_B"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["SUB_C"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

i need to include values of `id` and `title` to each path as expected result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "ROOT1"
    ["id"]=>
    int(35)
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(5) "SUB_A"
        ["id"]=>
        int(36)
        ["children"]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(7) "SUB_A_1"
            ["id"]=>
            int(39)
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(7) "SUB_A_2"
            ["id"]=>
            int(37)
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(7) "SUB_A_3"
            ["id"]=>
            int(40)
          }
          [3]=>
          array(2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(7) "SUB_A_4"
            ["id"]=>
            int(43)
          }
          [4]=>
          array(2) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(7) "SUB_A_5"
            ["id"]=>
            int(41)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "ROOT2"
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "ROOT3"
    ["id"]=>
    int(30)
    ["children"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(5) "SUB_B"
        ["id"]=>
        int(34)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(5) "SUB_C"
        ["id"]=>
        int(31)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. [Test](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c05c01377d5cbe953d6852ba772f6577e2badb3)

I used arrow functions to reduce the amount of lines and there are inline comments to explain what I did.

```
<?php

$data = [["id"=> "35", "title"=> "ROOT1", "path"=> "ROOT1"], ["id"=> "36", "title"=> "SUB_A", "path"=> "ROOT1>SUB_A"], ["id"=> "37", "title"=> "SUB_A_1", "path"=> "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_1"], ["id"=> "38", "title"=> "SUB_A_2", "path"=> "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_2"], ["id"=> "39", "title"=> "SUB_A_3", "path"=> "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_3"], ["id"=> "40", "title"=> "SUB_A_4", "path"=> "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_4"], ["id"=> "41", "title"=> "SUB_A_5", "path"=> "ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_5"], ["id"=> "1", "title"=> "ROOT2", "path"=> "ROOT2"], ["id"=> "30", "title"=> "ROOT3", "path"=> "ROOT3"], ["id"=> "34", "title"=> "SUB_B", "path"=> "ROOT3>SUB_B"], ["id"=> "31", "title"=> "SUB_C", "path"=> "ROOT3>SUB_C"]];

// The path is defaulted to an empty string, so the regex would return the highest level elements only because they don't have any `>`
function get_children($data, $path = '') 
{
    $results = array_values(array_filter($data, fn($item) => preg_match("/^{$path}[^>]+$/", $item['path'])));
   // This regex, uses the passed path (e.g ROOT1) and searches for elements with anything but another `>`, because `>` signifies an inner directory.
   // So this would return elements with a path like `ROOT1>SUB_A, ROOT1>SUB_B` but not `ROOT1>SUB_A>SUB_A_1` 
    

    foreach($results as $i => $result) {
       // then I iterate through the result to get the element's children
        $children = array_values(get_children($data, "{$result['path']}>"));
        
        if (count($children)) $results[$i]['children'] = $children;
        unset($results[$i]['path']); // Removing the path key from the array
    }
    
    return $results;
}

$format = fn($data) => get_children($data);
print_r($format($data));
```

Comment: Thank you for help, you make it so simple I can understand from your code comment.